# How to eliminate duplicates in a dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my controller I have created a ViewBag like this:

```
ViewBag.Author = new SelectList(db.Book, "BookID", "BookAuthor")
```

In my View, the dropdownlist is created like this:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("Author", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author)
</div>
```

The problem is that I have a lot of books with the same author, so the list has for example, the same author listed 3 times.
How can I make so that the list doesn't show duplicates?

Comment: Creating a `SelectList` from a `Book` table makes not sense. You need to be generating it from an `Author` table (how could you ever create the first `Book` and who could you ever assign a 'new' `Author`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I used book as an example. Let me reformulate it, how can I remove duplicated items from a table so that I can use it in a ViewBag? Imagine if the Author table has got duplicated authors and I want to do a dropdownlist with them, how can I make so that the list doesn't show duplicates?

Comment: Then use can use `.Distinct()` in a LINQ query, but again it makes no sense - why would you ever have duplicate `Authors` in an `Author` table